# can someone tell whats remove_punct_dict command is doing ?? and whats the output of last line command?

Tags: python, nltk

```
def LemTokens(tokens):
    return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]

remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)

def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))
```

can someone tell whats remove_punct_dict command is doing ?? and whats the output of last line command ?

Comment: `remove_punct_dict` is a dictionary whose keys are the character codes of all the punctuation characters, and values are all `None`. I don't know NLTK, so I can't explain what the last line does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove_punct_dict` is actually a dict collection of the Unicode value of all punctuation  found in string.punctuation with value None

```
remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)
```

What it simply breaks down to is for each punctuation in string create a `dict(ord(punct),None)` where ord is the inbuilt function in python for returning Unicode value of a corresponding character.

Lets review the last function:

```
def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))
```

This method starts making the given text lowercase and then removing the punctuations within the text using reference to remove_punct_dict we created earlier.

e.g. Thus `Hello World` becomes `hello world!` and then `hello world`

It then goes on to tokenize the words and hence now instead of `Hello World` we have `hello` and `world`.

The last function is for stemming the words into its simplest form. You can read more about stemming [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html). `hello` and `world` are already stemmed word using Porter stemmer and hence will remain unchanged. Thus the final output of my example is simply

`hello` and `world`.

Example:

```
import string
import nltk;

text = "Hello World! My name is bob and i own a dog, a cat and a chicken."
lemmer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()

def LemTokens(tokens):
    return [lemmer.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]

remove_punct_dict = dict((ord(punct), None) for punct in string.punctuation)

def LemNormalize(text):
    return LemTokens(nltk.word_tokenize(text.lower().translate(remove_punct_dict)))

print(LemNormalize(text)) # ['hello', 'world', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'bob', 'and', 'i', 'own', 'a', 'dog', 'a', 'cat', 'and', 'a', 'chicken']
```